# Angular + Karma-Jessie | How to mock private property of a component?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I declared this property on a component:

```
@Input() private origin;
```

Which have these properties

```
const origin = {
    'iban': string,
    'user': string,
    'description': string,
    'money': string
};
```

I want to test the service TransactionContextService to check if the component is truthy.

```
beforeEach(inject([TransactionContextService], (service: TransactionContextService) => {
    service.setOrigin(origin);
    service.setBenefactor(Usuals.getMockData()[0]);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormTransactionComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
}));

it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

> The problem is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'money' of undefined

I tried to use spyOn to initialize the input "origin" with the method *setOrigin*. But this not worked. I thought about using a mock of the service TransactionContextService, but it is the service that I want to test... ^^

So, it seems like iban, user, and description are initialized but money property is not. Should I mock setOrigin method of the service? How can I initialize a private property of a component?

Comment: data-bound properties must be TypeScript `public` properties. Angular never binds to a TypeScript `private` property.

Comment: Yes, it is the problem here. I realized the question because I do not know how to intialize this property using spec file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stub component.
https://angular.io/guide/testing#nested-component-tests

This way you can create a stub of your component with the properties you need.You would need to create the money property manually.

The following link further explains how to create a set fixture with the mocked component.